# Atomikos with MySQL JTA not working properly

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, atomikos

I'm currently working on Java application using Spring, Hibernate, etc. under Tomcat.
I tried to configure JTA using the Atomikos but It looks like I have a problem when flush is done :(

There's a lot of configuration so I'll put the major parts:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean" init-method="init" destroy-method="close">

<property name="xaDataSourceClassName">
<value>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</value>
</property>
</bean>

<bean id="atomikosTransactionManager" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionManager" />
<bean id="atomikosUserTransaction" class="com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction" />

<bean id="jtaTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" depends-on="userTransactionService,atomikosTransactionManager,atomikosUserTransaction">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="atomikosTransactionManager" />
        <property name="userTransaction" ref="atomikosUserTransaction" />
        <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels" value="true"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
   <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jtaTransactionManager" ref="jtaTransactionManager"></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>              
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
```

While starting a Transaction using the @Transactional, I'm able to run queries but when saving via Hibernate getCurrentSession() I'm getting the following exception: (when commit it done)

```
org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: The transaction was set to rollback only
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1024)
..

Caused by: com.atomikos.datasource.ResourceException: XA resource 'XADBMS': resume for XID '31302E38382E36382E32342E746D30303030313030303137:31302E38382E36382E32342E746D31' raised -5: invalid arguments

..

[11:36:30:534 (http-bio-8080-exec-3) org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl$2.mapManagedFlushFailure(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:179)]
 ERROR: HHH000346: Error during managed flush [XA resource 'XADBMS': resume for XID '31302E38382E36382E32342E746D30303030313030303139:31302E38382E36382E32342E746D31' raised -5: invalid arguments were given for the XA operation]
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that i found the problem! it's related to Atomikos bug which is related to MySQL.

After adding the pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection=true parameter to the connection URL or as a parameter inside the com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean Spring definition, It solved my problem.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosDataSourceBean"
        init-method="init" destroy-method="close">
...
<property name="xaProperties">
   <props>
      <prop key="pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection">true</prop>  
   </props>     
</property>
</bean>
```